# Getting data into a partial view or layout using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display information about the logged in user (username, company name, number of notifications, etc) in the layout and/or partial views.  These will be common on every page.  Is there a trick for getting this data to them, or is it a case of extending each model to have this information in them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest you can go for a child action and invoke it from the layout, By this way you can avoid carry out the information in all the view models.

Ex.

**Child action**

```
public class UserController
{
  [ChildActionOnly]
  public PartialViewResult UserInfo()
  {
     var userInfo = .. get the user information from session or db

     return PartialView(userInfo);
  }
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model UserInfoModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CompanyName)
...
```

**Layout view**

```
<header>
  @Html.Action("UserInfo", "User")
</header>
```

Comment: Great - exactly what I was hoping for.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can still create Master Page in MVC which looks good for your requirement. 
Check out this link to learn how to create partial views in MVC

[PARTIAL VIEWS](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/)