# ASP.NET MVC 4 shared page element containing user data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application, I have a log in box, which is included in the "_Layout" View and shared between all pages. After successful authentication, I would like to present some basic data about the logged in user (First Name, Score, etc.) instead of the log in box. Of course, it also needs to be visible on every page. What would be the best method of implementing this? How can I get the data? Below you can see the screenshots of the box and what I want to achieve.

Before log in:

[image: Before log in]

After log in:

[image: After log in]

Comment: I would recommend you to use inheritance on your viewmodels. Please, take a look at this answer I gave: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986251/razor-mvc-where-to-put-global-variables-thats-accessible-across-master-page-p/16987530#16987530

Answer (score 1):

I am using following:

```
@if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   //PartialView with Log In form
}
else
{
 // PartialView with after Login from
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's easy, I already have this in my project. The question is how to pass the data from the controller to the partial view? And in which controller the method should be?

Comment: @PGrejc In that case it is very complex question. You should show, what have you tried to do - your models, controller etc. You may have your methods in any controller you want. As to passing data - how it is different from passing any other data?

Comment: I've used the method described here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538367/getting-data-into-a-partial-view-or-layout-using-mvc4) and it worked perfectly for me. Now I have:
@if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //@Html.Action(...) renders partial view with log in form
}
else
{
    //@Html.Action(...) renders partial view with user data
}
Thanks for your help!